# Does the Angular Service Worker prevent other network requests while it's prefetching assets?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

Has anyone else seen the angular service worker prevent other network requests from coming through while it's prefetching?  For example, I have an angular app with 147 assets in the ngsw.json that the service worker tries to rip through on install.  If I try to login to my application during the prefetching, it looks like my login request gets added to a queue that only happens at the end of the 147 prefetch requests.  Wondering if I misconfigured something or if we could make the SW pre fetch... slower or with a slight delay in between so user requests can get a chance to go through?

I only noticed this when I test with a bad connection (ex. setting chrome network tab to 'Fast 3G'.)  It takes about a half second to get through each asset and they are not parallelized well, I'm assuming old phones behave that way.  API requests from the user in the application sit in `pending` state until all the prefetching has finished, then they go through and complete.

Did I misconfigure my application/service worker or is this behavior as designed?

Comment: is your login api hosted at the same domain as the front app?

Comment: The site and the auth api are on different domains

Comment: pretty strange behavior, as your sw is not related to login api at all in this case, maybe the reason is limitted bandwith

Comment: That's what I'm thinking

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Service Worker to not prefetch all `assets`, but to cache them only when those `assets` are requested. You can do that with specifying the `lazy` value for `installMode` config in `ngsw-confing.json`.

Here is the example of the `ngsw-confing.json` that would not prefetch all `assets` but it will cache them only when they are requested:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/favicon.ico", "index.html", "/manifest.webmanifest", "/*.css", "/*.js"]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": ["/assets/**", "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm not considering lazy is that I'm advertising that my application is available offline and how will I know if everything has been downloaded unless I prefetch everything?  Wouldn't this leave it up to chance that the user would lazily load only a portion of the app and then go offline and then start failing the lazy load chunks?